# Create .htaccess redirect rule that removes an extension of files served from the root but not sub-directories?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'd like to redirect all `.htm` documents in the root (i.e. `www.example.com/page.htm`) to remove the extension (i.e. `www.example.com/page/`) but not redirect `.htm` documents in sub-directories (i.e. `www.example.com/subdir/page.htm`).

How is that done in `.htaccess`?

Comment: please show your current .htaccess

Comment: "(i.e. www.site.com/page/)" - by the look, you also want to append a trailing slash as well? To clarify, what URL are you linking to internally?

Comment: I know how to add the / if needed, this is going from traditional website to wordpress.  so instead of /page.htm it goes to /page/ but only items in the root dir should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress directives (ie. before `# BEGIN WordPress`).

```
# Redirect "/<page>.htm" to "/<page>/"
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.htm$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive, as this already occurs later in the WordPress directives. (The order of the `RewriteEngine` directive does not matter - the *last* instance "wins".)

This removes the `.htm` extension from any requested URL in the root only and appends a trailing slash (as in your example). This also assumes `<page>` itself does not contain a dot.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change it to a 301, but only after you have confirmed that it works (to avoid potential caching issues).